# Is it possible to have a property that spans multiple lines in messages.properties?

Tags: internationalization, properties

is it possible to have a property that has multiple lines in messages.properties?

e.g. (my.property below)

```
my.property=This property will
be in two lines
my.property.two=Another property
```

I need this for help texts which I'll be putting in the properties file... and I don't want to do appends.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Write them like this (using backslash `\` as an escape character):

```
my.property=This property will \
be in two lines
my.property.two=Another property
```